# Understanding proof of proposition for Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

7.20 on page 213 of linear algebra done right,
An operator $T \in \mathscr{L}$ is normal if and only if $||Tv||=||T^*v||$ for all $v \in V$.
For one direction of the proof,
suppose $T$ is normal $\implies T^*T-T^*T=0\implies \langle(T^*T-T^*T)v,v\rangle=0\implies \langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,v\rangle \implies||Tv||^2=||T^*v||^2$.

I can't understand the implication of $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,v\rangle \implies||Tv||^2=||T^*v||^2$, I was think Im missing the piece that shows $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,v\rangle\implies\langle Tv,Tv\rangle=\langle T^*v,T^*v\rangle$,

Here is what Ive tried,  $\langle T^*Tv,v\rangle=\langle v,(T^*T)^*v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,(T^*T)^*v\rangle=\langle TT^*v,TT^*v\rangle=||TT^*v||^2=||T^*Tv||^2$

Comment: Your "missing piece" line is correct, and implies that the squared norms are equal, as you've shown.

Comment: What is your question? Are you struggling to write down a proof of the converse?

Comment: Do what you did, but only move one T or T*. So Treat T*Tv=T*(Tv) where Tv is the vector and T* is the operator. Is that what you are struggling with?

Comment: @Sammy Black I couldnt figure out why the implication work, but I think I know now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the proof of this result from the fourth edition of *Linear Algebra Done Right* (to be published around December 2023, plus or minus a few months). Perhaps the extra details included here will be helpful to you.
[image: proof that T is normal if and only if ||Tv|| = ||T^*v|| for all v]

Comment: Thank you, Big fan of the book!